# Error : System.PageReference Save() is referenced by Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference

I have a controller extention class and a visulforce page,
VF page had a reference to a method call save in the extension class
However, I renamed the method and the reference from VF page.

My problem is, when I validate my code with Force.com Migration Tool, it gives the error
**"...Error: The method System.PageReference Save() is referenced by Visualforce Page (..."**

***Extension Class's method;***

```
        ...
public Pagereference Send() {
    try {  
        return doSend();

    } catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,e.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }

    return null;
}

    ....
```

***VF Page's reference;***

```
    ...
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
        <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!send}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
    ...
```

***Error;***

[image]

Can anyone see what's wrong here?
any suggestions?

Comment: Did you include the updated page in your deployment

Comment: Yes I did, I merged all of my changes and I double checked, the change is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoying glitch with the compiler. You'll need to deploy an intermediate version of either the page without a reference to the save function, or the class with the new function plus a dummy save method (`public void save() { }` will suffice), and then a second deployment with the final version of your code. This rule doesn't apply to managed packages, though, only deployments for unmanaged code. I don't know of any workaround that involves less than two deployments.